# Need help in configuring Jenkins with Coverity. Getting Error Message

Tags: jenkins, configuration, build, coverity

I have to configure Jenkins with Coverity.Below versions I am using:

Jenkins: 1.509.2
Coverity: 1.5.0

However, I am not able to configure. It is throwing me below error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
  at jenkins.plugins.coverity.CheckConfig.checkStream(CheckConfig.java:197)
  at jenkins.plugins.coverity.CheckConfig.check(CheckConfig.java:97)
  at jenkins.plugins.coverity.CoverityPublisher$DescriptorImpl.doCheckConfig(CoverityPublisher.java:655)
  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
  at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:616)
  at org.kohsuke.stapler.Function$InstanceFunction.invoke(Function.java:288)
  at org.kohsuke.stapler.Function.bindAndInvoke(Function.java:151)
  at org.kohsuke.stapler.Function.bindAndInvokeAndServeResponse(Function.java:90)
  at org.kohsuke.stapler.MetaClass$1.doDispatch(MetaClass.java:111)
  at org.kohsuke.stapler.NameBasedDispatcher.dispatch(NameBasedDispatcher.java:53)
  at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.tryInvoke(Stapler.java:677)
  ... 63 more
```

Appreciate if anyone can share me the steps or any reference document/links which can detail steps for configuration.

Thanks Everyone!!!

Aditi

Comment: This is a known bug: https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-25186

Comment: Thanks @mainframer .. However, do suggest if we can have a workaround or any later fixes... I need to get this deployed and would appreciate any help!!! Aprreciate if you can share some examples to configure global setting and coverity configuration in job for Java builds. I am referring to https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Coverity+Plugin, but didn't help much.

Answer (score 0):

I've the same problem.  It is caused by incorrect coverity analysis path setting. Check your settings on every build jobs.